# Spring social signin and spring security custom authentication manager

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-social

I am trying to understand if i am handling my server authentication properly

I am creating a server that uses Facebook to auto login, plus i am using hibernate

I do that by making the same process that the default `JdbcUsersConnectionRepository`
but i always return a user. if not found.

> ```
> @Override
> public List<String> findUserIdsWithConnection(Connection<?> connection) {
>     List<String> ret = new LinkedList<String>();
>     ConnectionKey key = connection.getKey();
>     MyUser myUser = userService.getUserBySocialConnection(key.getProviderId(), key.getProviderUserId());
>     if (myUser == null)
>     {
>         MyUser user = userService.createUserFromConnection(connection);
>         String myUserId = String.valueOf(user.getId());
>         ret.add(myUserId);
>     }else
>     {
>         ret.add(String.valueOf(myUser.getId()));
>     }
>     return ret;
> }
> ```

So my `signIn` has this code. to sign in the user:

> ```
>    public String signIn(String userId, Connection<?> connection, NativeWebRequest request) {
>     MyUser user = userService.getUserById(Long.parseLong(userId));
>     Authentication authentication = SecurityToolbox.signInUser(user);
>     // set remember-me cookie
>     MyUser myu = (MyUser)authentication.getPrincipal();
>     userCookieGenerator.addCookie(String.valueOf(myu.getId()), request.getNativeResponse(HttpServletResponse.class));
>     return null;
> }
> ```

and the sign in code from the `SecurityToolBox` :

> ```
>   public static Authentication signInUser(MyUser user) {
>     List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = getAuthorities(user);
>     Authentication authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user, "", authorities);
>     SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
>     return authentication;
>   }
> ```

Right now all of this is handled by a `userInterceptor` that i wrote that handles reading the cookie if available and remembering the user if exists.
What is the best protected info that i can send to the user with the cookie for remember me right now i am sending the user id but that's not what i want

I would like now to let spring security handle my session/remmeberme/authentication process
but i don't really understand what i should be doing.

**First question**
Is my code enough to properly authenticate the user with the server?, in the next request. if i ask in the `userInterceptor` if `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() != null` i can safely assume that the user was logged in?

now i would like to have spring security to handle my authentication instead of doing it myself with an interceptor. so i thought about creating an authentication manager. but i don't understand what i needs to be authenticated in

> ```
>         public class CustomAuthenticationManager implements AuthenticationManager {
> public Authentication authenticate(Authentication auth)
>         throws AuthenticationException {}}
> ```

I don't have a username and password, I just authenticated with facebook to login so what do i authenticate with.
in general i have some knowledge gap here which i don't really understand what i should be doing to make everything stick together

**Second question** 
What exactly needs to happen in the `authenticate` function for my situation

**Third question** 
I would like spring security to handle session and cookies for remember me. i understand that there is a remember me token same as u/p token, but i still dont understand how i am supposed to use it in my situation.

**Forth question**
Right now the entire sign in process happens for every request (which is not a resource) that is send to the server. is that the way it is supposed to happen?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Lots of questions there. First, the code you wrote in the first box is actually already supported in JdbcUsersConnectionRepository via the ConnectionSignUp that can be injected. ConnectionSignUp is a strategy interface that you could implement to create a user if one isn't found by the JdbcUsersConnectionRepository. Checkout the spring-social-quickstart application to see an example of this in action.

Without reading it too deeply, your signin code looks fine, but I agree that it's a lot of work to essentially recreate everything that Spring Security already does inside of an interceptor. For that reason, the latest snapshot builds of Spring Social include tighter integration with Spring Security.

The new stuff has a SocialAuthenticationFilter that is a Spring Security authentication filter just like any other authentication filter and it plugs directly into Spring Security's filter chain. This authentication filter works by comparing the user's provider info with a previously established connection on the local app and will sign them in if a match is found. Otherwise, it redirects to a signup page.

From a functionality perspective, it does the same job as Spring Social's ProviderSignInController. It differs, however, in that it is very tightly integrated with Spring Security and thus all of the security stuff you expect (remember-me, authorities, etc) just work as you'd expect them to without much/any additional effort on your part.

Again, this is only in the very latest 1.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT builds, but I anticipate (barring any surprises) pushing a 1.1.0.M2 release early next week. If you want to see some examples of this in action, have a look at the spring-social-showcase-sec or spring-social-showcase-sec-xml examples.